# Invalid JSON syntax in progressive web app manifest.json file

Tags: javascript, json, manifest, progressive-web-apps

I get the following error when using the [Google Lighthouse extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lighthouse/blipmdconlkpinefehnmjammfjpmpbjk?hl=en) or other similar manifest.json validation services.

"ERROR: file isn't valid JSON: SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0"

The manifest works.  I get the "Add to homescreen" prompt and the manifest.json file is found in dev tools (Application / Manifest section) though the parameters of the file aren't shown.

I've checked the format against the [Google IO](https://events.google.com/io2016/) and that the MIME type is correct.  I'm lost as to what else to try.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're on Windows the above error may be because you have the **manifest.json** file saved with a **Byte Order Mark (BOM)**.

Saving without a **BOM** may fix the problem.

In Visual Studio use **Save As**, use the dropdown next to **Save** to select **Save with Encoding**, then pick **Unicode (UTF-8 without signature)**.

Comment: The last obscure error I had with a file not being recognized was because it was saved without a BOM...

Comment: I had the same issue on a Mac, saving the file without BOM also fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: I'm surprised this doesn't have 1000+ upvotes. Worked perfectly.